# need help translating 「本音を言うと自分の部屋で一人でいるほうがホッとできます。」

Tags: sentence

「本音を言うと自分の部屋で一人でいるほうがホッとできます。」

I tried to translate words separately but I couldn't seem to make sense of it as a whole sentence. Something about saying your real feelings (about something) when you're alone in your room? Also I'm not sure what the ホッと means.

Comment: This is likely to be closed, as this is not a translation website. If you want to keep it open, you should include an attempt at the translation, and maybe specify the part you are unsure about and why you are hesitant about it

Comment: right, my bad! I just edited the post again to include the translation I attempted.

Comment: ほっとする should be in any dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

「本音を言う」means "To speak one's true feelings"; however, when used in the form of「本音を言うと、…」or「本音を言えば、…」at the start of the sentence like this, it often means "To tell you the truth, (...)" or "Honestly( though), (...)" etc. The「…ほうが…」on the other hand denotes comparison to something else, and the「ホッとできる」is just the potential form of「ほっとする」, i.e. "to feel relieved". It's often written with katakana like this, but the meaning is the same as with the hiragana form.

As a whole, the sentence translates to something to the effect of "To be honest, I('m able to) feel more at ease when I'm alone in my own room", although the details would vary slightly depending on the context.